# Custom http status code for specific resource in IIS

Tags: http, iis, iis-7

I have a web site with a single 'app_offline.htm' file. How can i configure IIS to return it with specific status code (say, 209) instead of default one (200)?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to using the 'app_offline.htm' feature of ASP.Net could be to use the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), it has a [huge bag of tricks](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) and setting custom response codes is one of them.

If the content of the page is not important, only the response code, then with that module you can configure a rule that will return a blank response with a 209 code to *any* request as long as the rule is enabled.

That will materialise in your web.config as something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>       
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="app_offline" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="209" statusReason="System unavailable" statusDescription="The site is currently down for maintenance, or something." />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. As far as I understand the module works before the request enters ASP.NET pipeline. I start to think it's impossible to achieve at all :(

Comment: Yes the example I gave will handle the request by returning a blank response with the 209 code, without ever passing it on to ASP.Net.  Is that what you get, but not the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly! ASP.NET always returns content of app_offline.htm with 200 code for ANY request coming in. And I need to overwrite it (custom NLB scenario).

Comment: Ah ok, learned something new.  I've never used this feature of ASP.Net.  What I suggested would actually be more useful as an alternative to putting that app_offline.htm file up, by instead activating a rule that returns 209 to _all_ requests until you want the site to resume serving content.

Answer (score 3):

Since IIS has special handling for a file named 'app_offline.htm' in the root of your web site, this suggestion may not work, unless you rename the file. But, here it is anyway...

You can use an HttpHandler for this. In your web.config, add something like this:

```
<add name="app_offline_GET" path="app_offline.htm" verb="GET" type="namespace.classname,dllname" />
```

Obviously, substitute the proper info in the 'type' attribute.

In the HttpHandler, do something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
  context.Response.WriteFile("app_offline.htm");
  context.Response.StatusCode = 209;        
  context.Response.StatusDescription = "whatever";
}
```

Comment: This does not work, IIS still returns "503
Service Unavailable". And that's correct because your handler is managed one but 'app_offline.htm' explicitly tells to stop processing new requests so they don't hit the code.

Comment: Is it not possible to change the name of the file in your situation? If not, maybe an HttpModule (instead of an HttpHandler) would fire early enough in the processing sequence to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

To show specific content based on status code, you can let the response set the status code and map the content to show based on the code in the httpErrors section. See example in this post https://serverfault.com/questions/483145/how-to-add-a-site-wide-downtime-error-message-in-iis-with-a-custom-503-error-co

For the benefit of preservation, I will replicate the example below:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SiteDown" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="503" statusReason="Down for maintenance" statusDescription="will be back up soon" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

      <httpErrors existingResponse="Auto" errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File">
             <remove statusCode="503" subStatusCode="-1" />
             <error statusCode="503" path="503.html" />
      </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```