# Using (and enforcing) HTTPS in an APS.NET Core 2 Application

Tags: c#, https, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.0, hsts

I was doing research for implementing (and enforcing) HTTPS on an ASP.NET Core 2 application, and I saw [Enforcing HTTPS in an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl), but it got me confused. It mentions two methods: using `RequireHttpsAttribute` or using a URL rewrite, but in the warning at the beginning of the page, they mention that do NOT use `RequireHttpsAttribute` because it's doing a redirect, but isn't it what the URL rewrite is also doing? So, are we able to use any of them for Web APIs even if they receive "sensitive information" (as mentioned in the warning in the docs page).

Also, I have heard about HSTS, and I did some research, but it doesn't seem to me that there's a standard implementation for it in ASP.NET Core. I stumbled upon a few NuGet packages, but I couldn't find one from a more "official" provider.

Can you help me understand this please?

Comment: You should test the both of them to see what they are doing. If they are doing redirects (which seems likely) then yes the warning would apply to both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion may lie in that the goal of the article is about a non-WebAPI application. Thus the warning - do not apply to WebAPI's. Do not use either of the methods for WebAPI's.

- *Users* that connect to an application on **http**://example.com (by typing the url in a browser) should be redirected to **https**://example.com. This may be done using one of the two methods.
- *Applications* that connect to http://webapi.example.com (like a web application) should be **NOT** be redirected to https://webapi.example.com. Port 80 should either be closed or return status 400 (for [nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/196929/reply-with-200-from-nginx-config-without-serving-a-file) and [IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064922/custom-http-status-code-for-specific-resource-in-iis#answer-13081575), change the status codes in these answers to 400).

Users cannot be burdened with technical security details. Developers, however, should be fully aware and can do the connection directly to https without any redirect what so ever.

Considering your second remark about "official" support for HSTS, take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/a4aa4ebb98e5788bf78254e4f4a1b518a1f2454f/aspnetcore/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/samples/TagHelpersBuiltIn/Startup.cs#L42) from the asp.net core docs. To be fair, [this](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/892cebb27eb1487a10e07d70967e490ecb38bce8/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy/HstsMiddleware.cs) was only committed a few months ago (as part of [2.1 milestone](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2308)) as of this writing, not a lot of documentation yet.

Comment: Thank you @Tewr for your answer. I would really appreciate if you can provide me with example(s) of the second bullet you mentioned (applications that connect), and actually closing port 80 or returning 400 status. Thank you

Comment: *How* to do it is a different subject -- and quite well documented. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) is the starting point docs on hosting with core. But in any case, in a production setup I would be behind a reverse proxy such as nginx or IIS - just google on how to configure ports on either of those, there are thousands of guides.

Comment: How to set permanent 400 is a less frequent use case, edited my answer with links to some other questions