# IIS denyByRequestRate returns 403 instead of 429

Tags: http, iis, rate-limiting

I've setup a [denyByRequestRate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyrequestrate) restriction on my IIS website. When the caller exceeds the defined request rate it gets `403 Forbidden`.

Is there a way to change the HTTP response code to `429 Too many requests` in order to implement a proper retry policy on the caller side?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064922/custom-http-status-code-for-specific-resource-in-iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064922/custom-http-status-code-for-specific-resource-in-iis).

Answer (score 0):

Returning 403 is by design if you read any Microsoft article on this topic, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions

If your caller side requires 429 instead of 403 and you have no way to modify the caller code, then your only option is to develop your own IIS extension to hijack those 403 responses and translate them to 429.